# Some app is unable to connect on specific port or at all while firewall is disabled

Tags: iptables, firewall, ufw

I've strange issue and I cannot deal with it by self. I'm owning dedicated server from rent company. I'm hosting on it few applications, well many, for example standard apache2 web server or teamspeak server. I recently wanted to host application created in C# that I found on GitHub. Same application works under Windows fine but when I downloaded release for linux unpacked it and started it is not connecting to other servers while supposed to do since this is app for reading game chat on specific ports and pass it to another game servers. Of course I reach out to the creator of app but he or she answered that this is issue on my side and I believe that is true because when I ran debian on WSL same app from same release worked fine. I don't believe that I have firewall, I especially downloaded package for ufw and set it to disable so I've no idea what is blocking that specific app or ports that its trying to connect. Could someone advice where to look for issue?

Ok so app is supposed to connect to these ports:
15092
9778
19092
13778

I set for app chmod 744 and created separate account but it is not working even on root account tbh.

When I ran app it after few seconds says its unable to connect to servers that I listed in config file which is exactly same config file copied from local Windows version of same app and works.

Screenshot:
[image]

This is the story that I reported to the author:
https://github.com/spikeydragoon/Cross-Ark-Chat/issues/59

so I would need help to figure out what is blocking connection on these ports.

I've debian 10.10. I've also many apps like teamspeak, appache2, mysql, tbh I don't even remember what exactly is hosted on this server but nothing should interfere in any ports.

I'm beginner in linux administrative, I'm self learner I dig at google but the only thing I could found were about iptables and ufw thats why I decided to download ufw and disable it but it changed nothing.

Any words would be useful, I like resolve issues by self so I would be thankful at least for advise or pointing a way to figure it out.

edit: forgot to mention that hosting provider is ovh/kimsufi if that matter.

Comment: Did you try other methods of connecting to the targets on the ports in question? `nc target.domain 15092`

Comment: I dont have domain to the game server, only ip address, I used that command and it said connection timeout.
[00:41:49] root@ns3148735 {bartosz}#:>nc 46.251.244.123 15092
(UNKNOWN) [46.251.244.123] 15092 (?) : Connection timed out